# How to set State when value is derived from Array in React App

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a react App, which renders a table from an array in the state.

I am trying to have an "EDIT MODE" which transforms some fields into textbox's so that I can update each row in the table.

I'm not sure how I can handle the onChange event when the value is derived from an element inside an array in the state.
here is my code, I have explained the problem in the comments:

```
class AddProjectType extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            editMode: false
        }
        this.changeEditMode = this.changeEditMode.bind(this);         //Bind This so I can use this.setState
        this.changeProjectName = this.changeProjectName.bind(this);   //Bind This so I can use this.setState

    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchProjectTypes();      //This fetched the table from the nodejs server
    }
    changeEditMode() {
        this.setState({ editMode: !this.state.editMode });    //Convert into edit mode and change rows in the table to inputs
    }
    changeProjectName(event){
        //this.setState - Unsure how to set state of a particular array HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    }


    render() {
        if (!this.props.projectTypes) {
            return (
                <CenterLoader />   //loading the table from server - show loader
            )
        }
        else
            return (
                <div className="container">
                    <table className="ProjectType-Table">
                        <tbody> 
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    Id
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Project Type
                                </th>
                                <th>

                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            {this.props.projectTypes.map((projectType, i) => {    //RENDER ALL ROWS
                                return (
                                    <tr key={i}>
                                        <td>
                                            {projectType._id}
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            {this.state.editMode ?
                                                <input type="text" className="browser-default" defaultValue={projectType.name} onChange={this.changeProjectName}/>  //On change, I need to save back to the state this value
                                                :
                                                projectType.name
                                            }
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button className="btn btn-small mr-1" onClick={this.changeEditMode}>Edit</button>
                                            <button className="btn btn-small">Delete</button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                )
                            }
                            )}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            );
    }

}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { projectTypes: state.quizz.projectTypes };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(AddProjectType);
```

Comment: You tagged `react-redux`, do you want to handle this in a redux store or just in your component state ?

Comment: You can pass the index, here `i`, to the `changeProjectName` handler.

Comment: perhaps this is where my logic is wrong.. I use redux and have a store, and the props come from the state in the store... so how do I do it in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Attach `data-idx={i}` in the input like this,

```
<input type="text" className="browser-default" defaultValue={projectType.name} onChange={this.changeProjectName} data-idx={i}/>
```

In your `changeProjectName(event)` handler,

```
var index = event.target.dataset.idx; // Here you will get index
```

Comment: I'm confused here, `this.props.projectTypes.map((projectType, i)`. 
You are iterating `this.props` instead of `this.state`. Hence the changes you are going to make in the `state` with `setState()` will not reflect.